# Text increases in size when highlighted in Internet Explorer

Tags: adobe, aem, livecycle

How can I stop the text from increasing its size and adding space within the text when it is highlighted and rendered in Internet Explorer?

I'm using Internet Explorer 11, and when I rendered the Adobe Designer form in other browser it works fine the text stays in place and keeps its original font size.

This is a part of the screenshot, cant give the whole picture since its confidential.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRdwy.png)

Comment: Please share on how to configure this. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to be IE compatible, extra spaces in labels should be deleted. Should use indents, enter key (for newline) and tab key.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of things could be going on here. Considering it's specific to Internet Explorer, I'm going to guess that you have an add-on that's doing this.

> To view installed add-ons
>   Open Internet Explorer, select the Tools button, and then select Manage add-ons.
>   Under Show, select All add-ons.
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17447/windows-internet-explorer-11-manage-add-ons

It could also be an accessibility option in Internet Explorer, but I'm not aware of one that specifically does this.

Alternatively, it could be a plugin on the website. Without knowing a lot more about your web server configuration, it'd be very hard to tell/guess.

Comment: what add-on might affect the rendering of the form? any suggestions?

Comment: It has to do with the highlighting itself, correct? I'd guess some type of accessibility add-on.
You may also check the Ease of Access options in Internet Explorer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17456/windows-internet-explorer-ease-of-access-options

Comment: Also, do/did the PC that you're using ever have software installed for the visually impaired? I've seen software do odd things like this on a PC. Even after it was removed different browsers continued to act quirky.
Does Internet Explorer on a different PC behave similarly?